# Getting the focus on a particular field when a form loads - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I have a form with multiple input fields. When the form loads, I want the focus to go on a particular field.

So consider a form like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="fname" get-focus>
  <input type="text" ng-model="lname">
</form>
```

I have written a basic directive as such:

```
.directive('GetFocus',function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
      //what function call to use here ?

    }   
  } 
});
```

Comment: ^^ This is assuming that you have included jquery before angular.

Comment: Angular has dependent on a trimmed down version of jquery, which it has baked within itself. So even if jquery is not loaded, this will work.

Comment: I'd use $timeout(element.focus), just in case...